# Linking to the same reference many times (instead of writing it over and over), while inserting each time a page number to it: possible?

Tags: kindle, epub, annotations, reference-request

I am writing an ebook and I'm referring to several books many times. I could use the regular notes section and *cite the book 20 times per chapter*, but it's cumbersome.

What's the smartest way to deal with those repetitive references in an ebook?
(I don't know which format I'll choose: it could be the Kindle format or the epub.)

One (theoretical) way would be to write a single time the ref of one of my book (ex: James, H. (1937). Ambassadors. New York, NY: Scribner.), store it in a variable. When the reader clicks on the reference, the footnote link will retrieve the variable and the page number (of the specific reference). But it creates a bigger problem: it doesn't seem to be compatible with the notes section (after each chapter). (This kind of ref will probably link to a tool-tip. And in any case I'm not sure it will work with the main ebook reader).

Comment: What software are you using to write the book?

Comment: @Mark see my comment bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Since most epub3 readers and current Kindle models and apps support popup footnotes, the easiest solution would be to use footnotes for all book references.

What app(s) are you using to write your book?

Comment: `What app(s) are you using to write your book?` I did not choose one yet. I was thinking about Sigil (open source). What do you recommend?

Comment: ` the easiest solution would be to use footnotes for all book references`, which means, getting rid of the note section (after each chapter). Yes, it seems to be the right solution (I dont see any other option). Thanks!